# How to provide input to shell from python?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am running my python in ubuntu and trying to make a script that communicates with the shell. My script is simple

```
import os

os.system('sudo su - xyz')
```

when I run the script and try to login xyz, it asks for the password in my shell. But how do I send the password via the python script and just login.? Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: What happens if you run another command only containing the password? Or put a newline after `xyz`, then put your password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try piping the password into the commandline string.

NOTE: This is VERY insecure. Anyone has access to your python script will know your password and can get a hold of your system.

```
import os
password = 'ABCDEFG'
os.system('echo {} | sudo -S su - xyz'.format(password))
```

EDIT: Note adding `echo` and -S to `sudo`, so it can accept password from a pipe

Comment: That doesn't work. That's just going to run your password as a command and pipe it into the next.

Comment: Could you try `os.system('echo {} | sudo -S ls'.format(password))`. If it works, then the problem is with the command `su - xyz`. BTW: Not sure why you need to call `su` since you already get privileged access by `sudo`

Answer (score 2):

Piping a hardcoded password into stdin so that you don't have to input it for a command which requires sudoer privileges is **overthinking** it (in addition to being highly insecure).

Just assume in your Python script that you are root (i.e. don't execute commands with sudo).

```
import os
os.system('su - xyz')
```

Then launch your Python script with sudo.

```
$ sudo python foo.py
```

Unless you have some weird requirements, this is the most natural way to do it.

Comment: I still am asked by the password from the terminal when i run the script. I don't run the script as root.

Comment: Yes, of course. But what's the difference between inputting the password once when launching the script versus hardcoding it in your script? Not only is it really insecure, but it also doesn't scale if the password changes (you'll have to edit the script). It's just a very weird thing you're asking. But maybe I'm missing some requirement you have. :)